# cordova run android on emulator shows half black screen

Tags: android, cordova

[image]

I get the following output with half black screen with default cordova app on android emulator.

Cordova version: latest
emulator: api-16
emulator-device: nexus 4
hardware-acceleration : ON in avd

Comment: Same problem here. I am not sure how to handle. I cant connect over chrome developer tools either.

Comment: Have u tried running in physical device?

Comment: Nope. I have no device with that low API.